# Nginx controller + oauth2-proxy authentication flow failing

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, oauth2-proxy

Nginx ingress controller on K8s is not properly triggering authentication flow via oauth2-proxy for `/` path. How can I make it do this?

I have nginx ingress controller (v1.1.3) and oauth2-proxy (latest as of 23/6/2023) in a K8s cluster (1.22) and a web app (Kibana).

The Kibana ingress contains the annotations below.

```
nginx.ingress.Kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://<kibana hostname>/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri     
nginx.ingress.Kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://<kibana hostname>/oauth2/auth
```

- The deployment of Kibana, its service and the ingress seems to be ok, as I can access it via the browser at `https://<kibana hostname>/`.
- oauth2-proxy deployment, service and ingress seem to at least partially work, as the URL `https://<kibana hostname>/oauth2/sign_in` triggers a successful authentication flow with IdP and redirects back to `https://<kibana hostname>/`.

The thing that doesn't work is that the URL `https://<kibana hostname>/` does not trigger the authentication flow, rather it forwards requests to the Kibana backend service.

When requesting the `/` path in the browser

- I see setting the message `http2 header: "cookie: _oauth2_proxy=..`. in nginx-controller logs
- In the oauth2-proxy pod logs I see messages containing `GET - "/oauth2/auth" HTTP/1.1`
- In IdP logs I see a successful authentication
- I do not see "auth" response containing assertion attributes from IdP as when the URL is `/oauth2/auth`

What is going wrong that prevents the authentication flow via oauth2-proxy to function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by an incorrect setting of the Redirect URIs in the IdP, correcting this resolved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).